# Kendo UI stripping bootstrap styles

Tags: kendo-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 the following code is used for a Radio Group. This displays as a set of buttons that when checked set the button to the active state. (append the class `.active`)

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1">Option 1
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2">Option 2
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3">Option 3
</label>
```

Normal function in "checked" is the appended `active` class

```
<label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1">Option 1
</label>
```

When Kendo.all.web.js is used - all classes EXCEPT the `active` are stripped. Making the button change into a checkbox

```
<label class="active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1">Option 1
</label>
```

How can this be corrected? I can't see anywhere where the code is coming from that is doing this.

Comment: i also encountered some problems in the design of kendo.2013.2.716 and bootstrap 3 framework integration...